# Scrapy xpath not capturing tags

Tags: xpath, tags, scrapy, html-lists

I want Scrapy to extract the 'Round Size' in this case. But it turns out the Scrapy couldn't capture any child nodes li under dl.

```
response.xpath('//[@id="termsheet"]/div/section[1]/div/dl/li[2]/dt/span').extract()
```

The Xpath expression is generated from Chome inspect. And I test the expression separately, it could capture li tags. I enabled Ajax in Scrapy, and it could capture other dynamic items. Is there any other reasons leading to the data miss of Scrapy? Anyone who have encountered the similar problems?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.seedinvest.com/mf.fire/seed/termsheet loads "Round size" using some JavaScript, from data fetched from an API endpoint (in this case https://www.seedinvest.com/api/v1/entities/mf.fire/deal-fundraising-profile/seed -- you can inspect the network queries in your browser's "Tools" panel, e.g in Chrome)

The API endpoint returns data as JSON (there's quite a lot of data!), so you can feed it to std lib `json` module, like in the example below (using scrapy shell)

```
$ scrapy shell https://www.seedinvest.com/api/v1/entities/mf.fire/deal-fundraising-profile/seed
2016-06-06 11:36:56 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2016-06-06 11:36:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.seedinvest.com/api/v1/entities/mf.fire/deal-fundraising-profile/seed> (referer: None)
(...)
>>> import json
>>> d = json.loads(response.text)
>>> d['funding_round']['escrow_max']
1000000.0
```

Comment: Fantastic! I am new to Scrapy, since I enabled Ajax in Scrapy setting, and it did render the data within html. Why couldn't it capture this term sheet parts? It did on others.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath and extraction are wrong, not much I can explain, here, have the working code

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="termsheet"]/div/section[1]/div/dl/li[2]/dt/span').extract_first()
```

Unless of course the content is dynamically generated which you will have to use something like Selenium or scrapy-splash

Comment: Thanks for the help!. I tried your code but it didn't work. I could capture 'li' but not its child 'dt'. I count the number of child nodes of li. It shows 0. Scrapy didn't capture any dt under li. so I think it might not be the problem of expression.

Comment: It's because it's being loaded in Javascript if you take a look at the source code (not by inspect) you'll see that that the dt element isn't there